# Database and table not created on android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am new in android. I am trying to make simple signup and login system. I have used SQLite Database system. When the app is opened the database and table should be created but it is not happening to me. No database is shown in 'Android Device monitor' inside data folder. Here is code of class DatabaseHelper.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dairy.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user_account";
public static final String COL_1 = "id";
public static final String COL_2 = "full_name";
public static final String COL_3 = "address";
public static final String COL_4 = "contact";
public static final String COL_5 = "password";
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String tableUserAccount = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("
            +COL_1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, "
            +COL_2+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
            +COL_3+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
            +COL_4+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
            +COL_5+" TEXT NOT NULL)";

    db.execSQL(tableUserAccount);

}
```

And my Main_Activty class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btn, btn1;
DatabaseHelper database;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    database = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
        }
    });

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Where exactly are you looking for the database? Note that the app private folder where the databases go is really private and you cannot see inside it unless the device is rooted (e.g. an emulator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`AUTOINCREMENT`** can only be used as part of the **column type** designation and must immediately follow **`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`**.

You would have had an error along the lines of :-

```
08-18 14:23:18.865 12008-12008/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: mjt.so45722118, PID: 12008
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mjt.so45722118/mjt.so45722118.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE user_account(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, full_name TEXT NOT NULL, address TEXT NOT NULL, contact TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                    Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE user_account(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, full_name TEXT NOT NULL, address TEXT NOT NULL, contact TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
                                                       at mjt.so45722118.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:38)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                       at mjt.so45722118.DatabaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.java:24)
                                                       at mjt.so45722118.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

As such you need to change :-

```
+COL_1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, "
```

to

```
+COL_1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
```

You could even not code `AUTOINCREMENT` (probably not, as per, ***The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is usually not needed.*** [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)).

`INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` implies `NOT NULL` so that is not needed.

So I'd suggest just coding :-

```
+COL_1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
```

You could add the following lines to `MainActivity`, after `database = new DatabaseHelper(this);`:-

```
        Cursor csr = database.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(" + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + ")",null)
        String rowinfo;
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            rowinfo = "Row position=" + Integer.toString(csr.getPosition());
            for (int i=0;i < csr.getColumnCount();i++) {
                rowinfo = rowinfo + " Column=" + csr.getColumnName(i) +
                        " Value=" + csr.getString(i);
            }
            Log.d("TABLEINFO",rowinfo);
        }
        csr.close();
```

This would then display the following in the log to show you that the Database and table exists:-

```
08-18 14:09:27.053 7905-7905/? D/TABLEINFO: Row position=0 Column=cid Value=0 Column=name Value=id Column=type Value=INTEGER Column=notnull Value=0 Column=dflt_value Value=null Column=pk Value=1
08-18 14:09:27.053 7905-7905/? D/TABLEINFO: Row position=1 Column=cid Value=1 Column=name Value=full_name Column=type Value=TEXT Column=notnull Value=1 Column=dflt_value Value=null Column=pk Value=0
08-18 14:09:27.053 7905-7905/? D/TABLEINFO: Row position=2 Column=cid Value=2 Column=name Value=address Column=type Value=TEXT Column=notnull Value=1 Column=dflt_value Value=null Column=pk Value=0
08-18 14:09:27.053 7905-7905/? D/TABLEINFO: Row position=3 Column=cid Value=3 Column=name Value=contact Column=type Value=TEXT Column=notnull Value=1 Column=dflt_value Value=null Column=pk Value=0
08-18 14:09:27.053 7905-7905/? D/TABLEINFO: Row position=4 Column=cid Value=4 Column=name Value=password Column=type Value=TEXT Column=notnull Value=1 Column=dflt_value Value=null Column=pk Value=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the **semicolon** in the **create query**. Try this

```
String tableUserAccount = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("
            +COL_1+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, "
            +COL_2+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
            +COL_3+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
            +COL_4+" TEXT NOT NULL, "
            +COL_5+" TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: It does not matter. Semicolon is optional with `execSQL()`. (There was already a comment about it not being needed but it got deleted.)